# How to animate a background image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate a large image from left to right and right to left

What i am trying to achieve:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPdC-8hgSnk&feature=youtu.be

```
class Ex extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/image.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```